# Avoiding code duplication when defining Gherkin Given and When statements

Tags: tdd, cucumber, bdd, gherkin, scenarios

I raised a similar question, but worded it badly and so didnt really get the answers I was after.  Here is another attempt:

So I appreciate that Cucumber's Gherkin Given statements are analogous to test case pre-conditions. I appreciate some feel these should not involve user interaction, but for the sake of this question I am going to disagree with that view.

Here are three scenarios:

```
Scenario: Test a song can be played
Given I setup a new account and default user
When I add a "2nd" user
And the "2nd" user starts playing a song
Then I should see a song is playing

Scenario: Test a playing song being stopped (version A)
Given I setup a new account and default user
And I add a "2nd" user
And the "2nd" user starts playing a song
When the "2nd" user stops playing a song
Then I should see a song is not playing

Scenario: Test a playing song being stopped (version B)
Given a "2nd" user is playing a song
When the "2nd" user stops playing a song
Then I should see a song is not playing
```

So I appreciate that version B above is better from a business user point than version A.  However, from a code re-use point of view surely version B would require the Given statement to repeat the code used in the majority of the very 1st scenario?

Cheers,

Charlie

Answer (score 1):

So version B is the one to go for.

If a Given step definition (e.g version B) has actions made up of steps covered in other When step definitions (e.g. 1st scenario), I simply create a private method in the step definition (or elsewhere if used across step definition files) that both the Given and When statement can call as required. This abolishes the need for copying and pasting the code :-)

Comment: You are right, re-using the steps is essential when writing scenarios. I'm guessing you haven't heard of the Page Object Pattern? This pattern promotes the encapsulation of all actions which can be carried out on a page into it's own class. Using this pattern will aid you greatly. See this article which will make matters clearer http://blog.josephwilk.net/cucumber/page-object-pattern.html

Comment: Hi Fresh. Yeah am using an equivalent of POM since I am testing services rather than browser objects.  However, I still am adverse to copying and pasting even 3 or so lines of code for each step and therefore splitting out the private methods, with the POM code inside them was an additional layer of extraction, but one worth making :-)

Comment: Ah I understand. Yes, what you are doing makes a lot of sense.